# Random REFUSED_STREAM making a POST multipart form request

Tags: go

This is the code to upload an apk file (several MB) to appetize.io using golang:

```
func uploadToAppetize(file multipart.File, branchName string, displayName string) (result *AppetizeRes, ok bool) {
    file.Seek(0, 0)
    url, _ := getUrl()
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(&buffer)
    fileName := displayName + "/" + branchName
    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("file", fileName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error creating form file %v: %v\n", fileName, err)
        return nil, false
    }

    size, err := io.Copy(part, file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error copying apk file data: %v\n", err)
        return nil, false
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Copied %v bytes for uploading to appetize...\n", size)
    writer.Close()
    response, err := http.Post(url, writer.FormDataContentType(), &buffer) // Random error on this line
    if err != nil || response == nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error occurred uploading apk data to appetize.io: %v %v\n", err, response)
        return nil, false
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()
    if response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return nil, false
    }

    var appetizeRes AppetizeRes
    if err := json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&appetizeRes); err != nil {
        return nil, false
    }
    return &appetizeRes, true
}
```

However I am receiving an random error on the line http.Post(...). It returns a nil response and an error. The error is "stream error: stream ID 1; REFUSED_STREAM". It happens randomly but will surely happen the first time the go program make the request after launching.

This is the go version:

```
go version go1.8.1 darwin/amd64
```

This is the response header from the server if it doesn't fail:
[image]

I also run this program on another mac running go 1.6.*, I didn't remember I ever run into this issue on that mac.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: May be its related to transport protocol being used by net/http package (HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2) an nginx issue. [This discussion](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2506) may related to your problem. Set [`GODEBUG`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) to appropriate value for further mitigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in the golang standard library `net/http` that fails to handle the `REFUSED_STREAM` http/2 error properly.  This is what is likely going on:

1. golang client opens a TCP connection to the HTTP/2 www server, sets the maximum number of HTTP streams in the connection to 1000 and starts uploading immediately.
2. The HTTP/2 www server tells the golang client to only use a given number of streams, but the golang client has already started more than that amount of streams.
3. The HTTP/2 www server reacts to this by resetting the excess streams.
4. The lack of proper support for a retry in the golang `net/http` code causes the stream to fail after being reset by the server, and eventually the upload fails as well.

There is a ticket open about this issue on github: [x/net/http2: retry requests rejected with REFUSED_STREAM - golang/go/issues/20985](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20985/)

**This issue has been closed in the master branch, the fix will be included in future Golang version 1.10